# zoom on d3 bar chart or line chart on mouse drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts, zooming

I have a d3 bar chart with line chart.I want a feature like zoom on the mouse drag on selected area.
like [amcharts](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-chart-with-scroll-and-zoom/)
Drag the mouse across xAxis and the zoom behavior.Without panning.Most of the examples given are of panning.

Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Take a look at Brush-Controls https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls and maybe http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

http://bl.ocks.org/jroetman/9b4c0599a4996edef0ab

Comment: @olefrank thanks man.. its cool and what I am expecting !! :)